# Как редактировать SCSS

Tags: css, css3, sass, scss

Не могу понять как изменить шрифт.
http://fitness.ad-rocket.com.ua/
Хочу изменить основной шрифт в body
Но файла на который указывают инструменты разработчика просто не сущевствует.
С scss сталкиваюсь впервые.
В корне сайта лежат обычные Css и min.css но есть еще .css.map где как раз указывается путь к scss.
Короче вот такая непонятная для меня вещь. Уверен что все просто) Но до меня не доходит.

Comment: Измените шрифт в основном файле css

Comment: Пробовал не помогает

Comment: [Мой сайт/проект не работает. Можно я просто дам на него ссылку?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5263/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D1%83/5264#5264)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вроде там scss компилируется на сервере. Так что если вы смените css файл, scss все равно поменяет на свой css. 
В файле _reboot.scss 58 строчка, попробуйте сменить там шрифт.

Comment: Так вот в этом и проблема этого файла нет)

Comment: Стили находятся в bootstrap.min.css
Как вариант , можете в своем файле со стилями переназначить шрифт

body {
  font-family: Circe!important;
}

Comment: Александр спасибо большое!
Стили находятся в bootstrap.min.css